# Magento 1.9 add layout and template to custom module in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, adminhtml, template

When I try to create a custom module that shows two tabs on the main page with the option to change titles, backgrounds, and colors, I was successful in adding the module's tab in the admin area but wasn't able to add the layout and template.

any one can explain please , how i can do this?

here the xml files:

**app/etc/modules/Lern_Sample.xml/**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lern_Sample>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Adminhtml />
        </depends>
    </Lern_Sample>
</modules>
```

**app/code/local/Lern/Sample/Block/Adminhtml/Sample/**

**grid.php**

```
 `class Lern_Sample_Block_Adminhtml_Sample_Grid extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
  {
    public function __construct()
  {
       parent::__construct();

  }
 }`
```

**Sample.php**

```
   class Lern_Sample_Block_Sample extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
   {
      public function __construct() {}
   }
```

**app/code/local/Lern/Sample/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php**

```
   class Lern_Sample_Adminhtml_IndexController extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

   public function indexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->renderLayout();

   }
}
```

**design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sample.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <layout version="0.1.0">
          <lern_sample_index_index>
           <reference name="root">
             <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
           <reference name="content">
            <block type="Lern_Sample/index" name="Lern_Sample_index" template="sample/sample.phtml"/>
           </reference>
          </lern_sample_index_index>
         </layout>
```

**design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sample.phtml**

## Hello World

**config.xml**

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
     <modules>
    <Lern_Sample>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Lern_Sample>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <sample>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lern_Sample</module>
                <frontName>sample</frontName>
            </args>
        </sample>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <sample>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lern_Sample</module>
                <frontName>admin_sample</frontName>
            </args>

        </sample>
    </routers>
</admin>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <sample>
            <class>Lern_Sample_Helper</class>
        </sample>
    </helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <sample module="sample">
            <title>Sample Module</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <sample module="sample">
                    <title>Sample Module</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_sample/adminhtml_index</action>

                    <layout>
                        <lern_sample>
                            <file>lern_sample.xml</file>
                        </lern_sample>
                    </layout>
                </sample>
            </children>
        </sample>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: I think you have missed some files. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is to add xml in your admin module:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <lern_sample>
                <file>lern_sample.xml</file>
            </lern_sample>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

You need to add it under adminhtml not menu.
Below is the code for your layout xml (**lern_sample.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
    <module_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
            <block type="module/index" name="module_index" template="module/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
    </module_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Comment: in here type="module/index" name="module_index" i need to change instead module, name of the module?

Comment: Yes you need to change the block type and your template path also the handler which is <module_index_index> and </module_index_index>. You can leave the name as it is but change the name according to your module will be good.

Comment: thank you but nothing change((( and i need it very mutch....

Comment: i see the tab in admin panel, routing to the page but without view... page is blank

Comment: Can you post your whole module code here?

Comment: yes just a second please

Comment: i have upgraded the post

Comment: I ll get back to you.

Comment: i all ready fix this and i'm getting closer. thank you. but now i get white screen without errors

Comment: So everything works?

Comment: now. i got white screen

Comment: with no errors on screen

Comment: Can you post the codes as you missed some files?

Comment: i don't have any others. what it can be?

Comment: Menu is not showing for me. I need acl config is missing.

Comment: acl? config? what you mean?

Comment: for menu you need acl. Are you able to see menu?

Comment: no only white screen

Comment: What is your requirement. i ll create the new extension with error free.

Comment: modules config - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lern_Sample>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>

        </Lern_Sample>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: no need dude. i want to understand what is wrong i removed rows that depends on admin default template

Comment: Ok then continue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80122/discussion-on-answer-by-sukumar-gorai-magento-1-9-add-layout-and-template-to-cus).